# I am getting Unable to save file: Permission denied in atom when saving running ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, atom-editor

I just installed Atom, and I am getting an error thrown up when I go to save the project.

> Unable to save file: Permission denied

I am signed in with admin privileges.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This isn't an atom problem, it's a linux permissions problem.

You opened a file owned by another user (a file probably owned by `root`). If you want to edit that file, you have to either *be* root or change the permissions on the file to grant other users access.

Usually the best solution is to temporarily become root and edit the file:

```
sudo atom /path/to/file
```

Comment: In my opinion, this **is** an Atom problem, because Sublime asks you for root password when you try to save a root owned file. Atom should be able to do the same.
Your solution works just fine, but Atom comes with default settings (wich can be really annoying depending on the user).

Comment: also in pycharm there is no need to do anything

Comment: I have packages installed for dealing with the format of configuration... When I use "sudo atom blabla" the packages obviously aren't installed, it is using root's atom profile. this is little more than only annoying, but really, why can't atom ask for a password or something like that? There are tons of software that to this...

Comment: It gives an error: /usr/bin/atom: line 190:  4457 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) nohup "$ATOM_PATH" --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@" > "$ATOM_HOME/nohup.out" 2>&1
[4457:0803/094258.984713:FATAL:atom_main_delegate.cc(194)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

Answer (score 19):

Try running:

```
sudo chown -R username:www-data /path/to/directory
```

"username" being what gets spit out when you enter

```
whoami
```

Digital Ocean's tutorials are pretty good for installing stuff the right way. I got the above from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lamp-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 16):

This is because of linux permissions. The best way to solve this problem is by providing permission for the user. This can be done by chown command.

```
sudo chown -R username:groupname directory
```

You can find your username using `whoami` command and your group name by using `groups username` command.

Let's say you got "john" as your username. To get groupname you run the command

```
groups john
```

You will get an output something like this

```
john : john staff adm cdrom lpadmin admin
```

The first name after `:` is your primary group. In the example it is "john"

The command will be

```
sudo chown -R john:john /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

Answer (score 7):

if your case is same situation as this screenshot

[image]

try this

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.atom
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because linux don't have permissions. The best way to solve this problem you have to provide permission for the user to access particular directory/folder or file.

**Please follow the below steps to give permission.**

First find your username by entering the following command in console.

```
whoami
```

You will get an output something like this

```
jrathor
```

You got "jrathor" as your username.

Now provide permission to that particular folder/directory or file which one you are not able to access.

```
sudo chown -R jrathor /path/to/folder/or/file
```

Now you can edit all the files which is available in directory.

It Will work for ubuntu as well as for MAC also.

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error in ubuntu 20.04 as well, I found a solution.

1. In terminal(ctrl + alt + t), you can access to root using this order 'sudo su'.
   Give your password then go to the directory exactly atom want to save.
2. First,'cd' to find right directory. then again, 'cd /usr/bin'.
3. Now you are in the directory /usr/bin. Type 'touch atom'. It will make atom txt file in your path. And type 'exit'
4. sudo chown -R username:www-data /path/to/directory
   "username" being what gets spit out when you enter

whoami as @sam said above.

5. Go to atom, try save the file again. atom will be saved successfully.

Answer (score 0):

before run your file with atom , if you change your file write permission other users can save it 
you can read from here for permission [linux-permission](http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/change-file-permissions-linux/)

$su -

password:

chmod 777 index.php

open new terminal and run your file with texteditor

$ atom /var/www/html/wordpress/index.php

Answer (score 0):

there is alot of ways to solve this problem, i just change the permisions on the proyect folder:
sudo chmod 777 /path/to/folder/proyect

Comment: Add the recursive flag: "sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/folder/project" to apply this to all files in the project folder

Comment: 777 permission to web directory ? Invitations to multiple attackers..

Answer (score 0):

It might be late to answer this, but I tried this and resolved my issue:

**(Disclaimer : I tried to save changes in keymap.cson file in atom, got error : Unable to save changes : Permission denied)**

```
chmod 777 <file name>
```

and after that,

1. go to the file "keymap.cson".
2. right click and go to properties.
3. un-check hidden check-box.

you are good to save changes in keymap.cson in atom

Happy saving :)

Answer (score 0):

This same problem occurred on my Mac running OSX.

Problem:

for some reason npm created the react app with Read & Write permissions to System for only the app folder, although all files and folders contained had read/ write permissions to me, the creating user.

Solution:

You'll need the admin password.
Visit the app folder in Finder, like, "directory/ReactApps/react-app/...", right-click and click the dropdown menu for "Permissions", click the padlock icon in the bottom right of that pane and enter the admin password, create a new user by clicking "+" icon, select yourself, and Read/Write permission, click the (unlocked) padlock icon again.
Copy your current code in Atom, quit Atom (cmd+q), restart, select the file, select all (cmd+a), paste, then save (cmd+s).

Onward

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS cloud 9 lightsail (magento in my case) use:

> sudo chown -R bitnami:bitnami /opt/bitnami/apps

this will allow you to have full access to your file tree to create new folders and files. (may do more not sure, as im now to this).

Thank you,